# Limits in overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I am currently considering to use overleaf for the first time. But there are listed some limits:

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/What_is_the_maximum_compilation_time,_file_number_and_project_size_allowed_on_free_vs_paid_plans%3F

I believe those limits are not too strict, but for example "Maximum total size of editable material per project: 7 MB" seems strict. What does that mean exactly? What is "editable material"? Also "Maximum size of an individual editable text file: 2 MB" - what is an editable text file? If it is what I think, that seems actually a bit restrictive, because there is likely a limit of several hundred pages to be used. On the other hand, "Maximum size of an individual upload: 50 MB" seems quite a lot. I am a bit confused.

Can someone explain what these limits imply or when they actually play a role? Thanks.

Comment: presumably things like images count towards the total project but not "editable material"  Not many documents require7MB of tex source do they? (note I have no relation with overleaf don't take my comments as authoritative)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @DavidCarlisle that's what I was hoping.
Besides I have a document of about 100 pages, and it is already about 200 KB of size. That would mean 7 MB equals about 3,500 pages of a limit. That would be negligible for almost any use case I believe.

Comment: Hi there, Tom from Overleaf support here. I'll make a slightly more detailed answer to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Tom from Overleaf support here.)*

**Text files.** The 7MB of total editable contents, and 2MB for a single file shouldn't be a problem if you write standard text; as you realized 7MB of contents is several thousand pages, given contents is plain text. Every file that can be edited directly in the Overleaf text editor counts towards the contents. Usually, it's not an issue. Mostly you can reach the limit only with some extemities, which include:

- Extreme .bib files that include full abstracts or even hex/base64-encoded PDFs.
- Large datasets (CSV files and similar).
- Extreme code listings. (It's imaginable that someone has 7MB of code they want to display.)

**Uploads.** The limit on a single upload is 50MB. It is possible to have projects larger than that, by either adding the large files into the project one by one, or using the Dropbox sync.

**Compile time.** Note that if a project nears any of the two limits (7MB text, 50MB total), it will most likely fail to compile in the given 1- or 4-minute timeout. Maybe a project with 50MB of JPGs or directly includable PDFs would be compiled in 4 minutes, but chances still are it wouldn't.

**Bottom line.** As long as you use Overleaf/LaTeX in a reasonable way, you should never reach any of the file size limits in place.