# Classic Thesis v.4.2 compile timeout

Tags: compiling, overleaf, classicthesis

I am using the Classic Thesis template version 4.2. It has always worked, but now suddenly there is the "compile timeout error". I didn't change anything.

This happens even if I use the fast[draft] mode, or open the original template.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you

Comment: "compile timeout error" is not a typical LaTeX error. Are you using a time limited system like Overleaf? Can you show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), that would allow us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Overleaf have reduced their time allowance

Comment: If you are using Overleaf, see for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/572999 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/641662 or

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/blog/changes-to-free-compile-timeouts-and-servers

Comment: @cabohah yes but specifically this month  see ^^^

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for the link.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Does this mean that even already available templates might take too long to compile? How am I supposed to overcome this problem without paying?

Comment: @cabohah yes I am using Overleaf, but I don't know what example could I show you, since I did not change anything from yesterday.

Comment: Not sure of the details I have no inside knowledge, i just saw that blog the other day. First you should check that is the issue and you do not have an error causing a loop or some such. Overleaf support should be able to tell you when/if you were moved to the new scheme, I would think

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, I will try to contact Overleaf support.

Comment: Do you know any other editor which might work for me now?

Comment: personally (except when testing overleaf for answers here) I always use a locally installed tex so there is no time limit at all.

Comment: If your document really compiled **yesterday** and not, say, ten days ago, then it shouldn't be due to the reduction in the time allowance. According to the blog @DavidCarlisle linked, the rollout of changes was completed on 30th October. But, of course, unless you really haven't changed anything at all, you might have hit the limit. And I suspect the answer to 'how am I supposed to [do this] without paying?' is that Overleaf obviously need people to pay. Check whether your institution/organisation subscribes. If you don't use your official email, Overleaf won't know to offer you this option.